# Is there a way to hide the Google Calendar sidebar / navigation pane?

Tags: google-calendar

Preferably I want to be able to toggle the sidebar on and off. I tried several user scripts on Chrome but they didn't seem to work.

Comment: which did you try?

Comment: I searched greasyfork.org and tried all scripts I could find. I also tested several scripts from Userscripts.org without success. For testing, I used a clean profile in chrome, only installed tampermonkey and confirmed that the script was active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installation**

1. Install [User JavaScript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld) or another extension that allows adding custom CSS.
2. Open google calendar
3. Add a new CSS rule

The URL for the CSS rule should be: `calendar.google.com`

The css code should be: `.AOL3Kb { display:none; }`

**Usage**

To toggle the sidebar, activate or deactivate the script in the [User JavaScript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld) extension menu and reload the page with the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## **Script for Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Google Calendar - Resize Navigation Sidebar
// @namespace   calendar.google.com
// @author cbop-dev (https://github.com/cbop-dev)
// @version 0.3.8
// @description Makes the G-Cal navigation sidebar re-sizable and hideable. Adds a column 
// border and drag-button that can be dragged with the mouse, and a show/hide toggle button.
// @license MIT License (Expat)
// @include       https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render*
// @grant       none
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
//window.alert('test');
var i = 0;
var dragging = false;
var main = $('#mainbody');
var nav = $('#nav');
var defaultPosition = '225';
var lastPosition = defaultPosition;
var minNavPosition = 35;

var ghostbar = $('<div>',
                 {id:'ghostbar',
                  css: {                                
                      'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
                      height: '100%',
                      top: '0',
                      'margin-left': $('#mainbody').css('margin-left'),
                      'width': '3px',
                      'cursor': 'col-resize',
                      'float': 'left',
                      'position': 'absolute',
                      'z-index': '50'

                  },
                  class: 'ghost'
                 }).appendTo('#maincell');

var ghostEZdragbar = $('<div>',
                       {id:'ghostEZdragbar',
                        css: {
                            height: 'auto',
                            'min-height': '10px',
                            top: '0px',
                            'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
                            'margin-left': $('#mainbody').css('margin-left'),
                            'width': 'auto',
                            'cursor': 'col-resize',
                            'float': 'left',
                            'position': 'absolute',
                            'z-index': '50',
                            color: 'white',
                            'text-align': 'center'
                        },
                        text: '\u25C4\u25BA',
                        class: 'ghost'
                       }).appendTo('#maincell');

var ghostToggleNav = $('<div>',
                       {id:'ghostToggleNav',
                        css: {
                            height: 'auto',
                            'min-height': '7px',
                            top: ghostEZdragbar.css('height'),
                            'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
                            'margin-left': $('#mainbody').css('margin-left'),
                            'width': 'auto',
                            'cursor': 'pointer',
                            'float': 'left',
                            'position': 'absolute',
                            'z-index': '50',
                            color: 'white',
                            'text-align': 'center',


                        },
                        class: 'ghost',
                        text: '\u2715'
                       }).appendTo('#maincell');

ghostEZdragbar.css('left',"-" + ghostEZdragbar.css('width'));
ghostToggleNav.css('left',"-" + ghostToggleNav.css('width'));

function moveNav(x) {
    $('.ghost').css('margin-left', x );
    $('#mainbody').css('margin-left', x);
    $('#nav').css('width', x - 32);
}

function hideNav() {
    moveNav(0);
    $('#nav').hide();
}


var mouseMoveNav = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    dragging = true;

    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        if (e.pageX >= minNavPosition) {
            $('.ghost').css('margin-left', e.pageX + 2);
            //ghostEZdragbar.css('margin-left', e.pageX + 2);
        }
    });
};

ghostbar.mousedown(mouseMoveNav);
ghostEZdragbar.mousedown(mouseMoveNav);
ghostToggleNav.on('click', function(e) {
    if ( ghostbar.css('display') == 'none' ){ //already hidden; toggle to visible
        ghostToggleNav.text("\u2715");
        ghostToggleNav.css('width', 'auto');
        ghostToggleNav.css('top', ghostEZdragbar.css('height'));
        $('#nav').show();
        moveNav(lastPosition);
        ghostToggleNav.css('left',"-" + ghostToggleNav.css('width'));
        $('.ghost').show();
    }
    else { // visible, going to hide nav bar:
        lastPosition = $('#nav').width() +40;
        $('.ghost').hide();
        hideNav();
        ghostToggleNav.css('top', '0px');
        ghostToggleNav.css('left', 0);
        ghostToggleNav.text('\u25BA');
        ghostToggleNav.css('width', 'auto');
        ghostToggleNav.show();
    }
});

window.onload = function() {
    //window.alert("Onload!");
};

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (dragging)
    {
        moveNav(e.pageX > minNavPosition ? e.pageX : minNavPosition);

        $(document).unbind('mousemove');
        dragging = false;
    }
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    if (location.hash.lastIndexOf('#main', 0) === -1) {
        $('.ghost').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.ghost').show();
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get minimalist working properly. There are several comments pointing out that the extension seems to be abandoned.

Comment: I tested the script with Tampermonkey and it is not working. I guess the script is not updated for the new google calendar version. For instance, I see that `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render*` should be `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r*`. But even when I change the url include the script is not working.

Answer (score 1):

[Benjamin's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119031) is correct even though it did not work for me as-is. The reason it did not work was the name of the object, the left panel, was not `AOL3Kb`, but instead `QQYuzf`.

To find this, simply right click on the panel, click *Inspect*, and locate the name for the pane. You may move your mouse over the html and it will highlight the respective area/object; you want the second highest line in the html that highlights the entire left pane. Next, simply copy the name, `IDYouWant` in the example below, and substitute it in the CSS script.

e.g.:

```
<div class="SomeID">
  <div class="IDYouWant" jsname="AnotherID">
```

Your script will then look like: `.IDYouWant { display:none; }`

Comment: It sure looks like these IDs are generated on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

This would be better as a comment, but I can't do that so...

As MCWS pointed out Benjamin's answer is correct, but the ID is wrong. Furthermore with Google's current UI at the time of writing, the "sidebar" should be considered to include the "Create" button that hovers over it as removing only the sidebar results in part of the calendar display being occluded. This means the new css code would be:

```
.QQYuzf { display:none; }
.dwlvNd.Hrn1mc { display:none; }
```

QQyuzf is the sidebar, and dwlvNd.Hrn1mc is the create button. The IDs do not appear to be generated ad hoc as Alex surmised since QQyuzf has been the sidebar ID for at least several months now, if not much longer. Do expect them to change eventually though. You may use the element picker in DevTools (top left button when pressing F12) to find the new IDs when they change.